# Does Ubuntu 12.04 have a sounds folder to help set my email notification?

Tags: sound, notification, indicator-sound

Does Ubuntu 12.04 have a stock sounds folder with some sounds I can use to  set my email notification and other kind of notifications?

I am looking for something centralized, like in `/usr/share` not a custom one in my own home folder.

Comment: You can try this one /usr/share/sounds/

Comment: Thanks. I found some files there. I thought of it but there just seemed to be too many folders in /usr/share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of sound files are found in `/usr/share/sounds` . Therefore one can use it to change default system sounds(email notification sounds in this case). One has to remember that sound files in the folder are in `.ogg` format and therefore the sound files that one is going to set up instead of the default system sounds must also be in `.ogg` format.